# Is there a way to completely erase my remote git repository?

Tags: git

I know that it's possible. I've made that long time ago but until now I couldn't find any solution to properly empty a remote repository.

My goal is:
1. Empty everything on remote repo
2. Commit all my files from local repo as a new starting project

Comment: Yup, 2) I want to remove files and commits.

Comment: What is the original task for such a weird question?

Comment: Yes: 1. go to the computer which contains the remote git repository. 2. delete the repository there.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether the remote accepts fast-forwards and modifying history.

It that case you can make a clone. Be careful, use a new temporary local repository (while maintaining the old one), otherwise the local repository will be cleared as well.

```
git clone url folder
cd folder
```

remove everything from the entire history

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch *' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

and force a push to the remote

```
git push -f origin
```

Some remotes however (like BitBucket) allow the administrator to protect branches against historical rewrites or removal, in that case the remote will throw an error. From the moment you use a remote, you will have to thrust that the remote will not abuse the information you provide.

Comment: So how are you going to change the pushed changesets?

Comment: Well by using the `-f` flag, you "force" to revise the entire history and thus removing all the commits. However as I already said, it is possible the remote will not accept this.

Comment: uhm, it's still not clear how exactly `-f` is going to remove anything. You've pushed something additionally to what is already there. What exact command will drop the existing DAG nodes?

Comment: Not entirely. In most cases this is the effect of push. However if the `HEAD` is not the same anymore,  `git push` will compare the two repositories and make (more or less) a copy of the local repo to the remote repo (an empty one in this case). Without `-f`, only new commits can be pushed.

Comment: But won't be the old history still be available in a reflog? `HEAD` is just a pointer, it has nothing to do with data

Comment: No. You remove all the commits, since you move all the files all commits become irrelevant and are dropped. So no historical data available anymore. You can test this by cloning the repository a second time and looking to the `git log`

Comment: just run your commands - the commits are in reflog (not surprisingly at all). So "recovery" will take literally one command run on a server

Answer (score 1):

How about just creating a fresh new repository, add a remote that points to the one that you want to wipe out, and force update?

```
cd /folder/with/new/files
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'added files'
git remote add origin URL_TO_REPO_TO_WIPE
git push -u origin master -f
```

**UPDATE**

To really wipe out everything, there is one more step: delete all other remote branches except master:

```
git fetch origin
git branch -r | cut -d/ -f2- | grep -v master | xargs -i{} git push origin :{}
```

I suppose the old commits that are now unreferenced will still survive this. To be honest I don't know the details of how that works. I think orphaned commits should get deleted at some point when the remote repo is periodically compacted, I think GitHub does that, for example. If it's important to you to really wipe out all stale references, then you should find out from the host of your repo. (If you own the server then it would have been easiest to recreate the repo yourself, of course, and then all this discussion here is pointless...)

**For [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms)**

I tested that commits are wiped out locally using these commands:

```
cd /some/repo
git clone --bare . /tmp/oldrepo.git
git init /tmp/newrepo
cd /tmp/newrepo
date > date.txt
git add .
git commit -m start
git remote add origin /tmp/oldrepo.git
git push origin -f
cd ..
git --git-dir oldrepo.git rev-list --all
```

This last step shows only the one commit I force-pushed. But as I explained above, I'm pretty sure some orphaned commits are still hanging there, as I think you are suggesting too. If you could tell me how to confirm those that would be nice, and then maybe I could improve my answer.

Comment: I tried this on a repo in github, *before* I posted. It works, and of course it does, why wouldn't it? As for `git reset`, it's not natural here. The OP basically wants to overwrite a repo with a new repo. So do exactly that! He didn't say he wants to wipe out his local repo. I even have a practical use case for you. My subscription allows me max 5 private repos on github. Sometimes I overwrite a private repo with another local repo I want to have online, to stay within my limit. And usually I still want to keep the old one locally.

Comment: we don't know the exact task (I asked about it in the comment and OP didn't answer) and cannot be sure if it's acceptable or not. Your and another answer *erase nothing*. The history still stays on the server. If the original reason is to completely drop history and free space it takes - then the proposed solutions won't solve that.

Comment: Yes, too often we have to *guess* what the OP may or may not want, and we make assumptions. We might never even know who was right. Anyway, I agree with your last comment at least partly. I did some more tests and updated my answer.